# Alternative Compactification of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, compactification

Of course, there is the compactification of $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, which allows us to correspond the complex plane to the unit sphere. Is there any use in compactifying $\mathbb{C}$ with something like $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\theta\infty|\theta\in[0,2\pi)\}$ (pardon my abuse of notation) which essentially adds a point at infinity for EACH direction around the plane?

Comment: It seems like the projective plane you're describing, though in that case no particular advantage comes from thinking of the usual Euclidean plane as $\mathbb C.$

Comment: I should adjust the above comment with the note that in the projective plane, the two infinite points added corresponding to a single line are "identified" to a single point at infinity in that "direction". Also one considers every line in the plane to give the infinite points, not just those through the origin.

Comment: Isn't this homeomorphic to the closed disk?

Comment: How do you topologise the points at infinity?

Comment: @CJDowd Yeah I think so

Comment: @FShrike I'm not sure. I was hoping someone had already heard of this and knew what topology it's usually given.

Comment: Well, you could topologise these points to make this a copy of the closed disk. Or you could do whatever you like with them.